# How optimize row filtering in numpy matrix using Cython?

Tags: numpy, cython, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to filter rows in a np.ndarray with a column condition. Usually i use this code:

```
def filter(data,column_index,threshold):
    left = data[data[:,column_index] <= threshold] 
    right = data[data[:,column_index] > threshold] 
    return left,right
```

But i have a large dataset and thresholds, so i need to optimize the time of execution. Is there a way to optimize this code using Cython?. My try:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def filter(data,int column_index,float threshold):
    cdef np.ndarray left = data[data[:,column_index] <= threshold] 
    cdef np.ndarray right = data[data[:,column_index] > threshold] 
    return left,right
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `threshold` does not contain any `NaN`, the values smaller or equal are not greater and vice versa. Thus, you can store the boolean values `data[:,column_index] <= threshold` temporary not to **compute again** the second comparison.

Moreover, the comparisons create multiple **temporary arrays** that can be avoided by creating one big temporary array, then iterating over the values and put them either to the left or the right of the big array, then the big array can be sliced to return the left and right part. This method is called a *partition*.

Besides this, the biggest problem comes from the fact that the first dimension is not contiguous. Since the array should be big, there is a good chance that it does not fit in the CPU cache (so it is stored in RAM) and `data.shape[1]` is not small. As a result, fetching non-contiguous data from the RAM with a large stride is pretty inefficient. The computation will likely be bound by the **memory latency**. There is not a lot you can do in Cython, apart using the above methods (or perform a local contiguous copy if values contain `NaN`). If `data` is really huge (> 100,000 x 100,000), you can use multiple threads to mitigate the latency cost. Otherwise, the cost to create threads, distribute the work and gather results will be likely to big to worth using threads. Note that you could adapt the input data structure so that accesses are more contiguous if this is possible (probably not).